# How to download all versions of a file with PnP

Tags: pnp-powershell, version-history

Is it possible to download all versions of a file with PnP? (with Get-PnPFile I guess, targeting SharePoint-2013)

The closest I've found was with help of [how-do-i-get-the-version-of-a-file-using-pnp-powershell](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint-developer/how-do-i-get-the-version-of-a-file-using-pnp-powershell/m-p/156100), but I'm stuck on downloading the versions.

```
$ctxt= Get-PnPContext
Get-PnPListItem -List <a Document Library> `
    | Where-Object { $_.FieldValues.Title -eq "a title" } ` # a requirement
    | Foreach-Object { 
        $f = $_.file; 
        $versions = $f.versions; 
        $ctxt.Load($f); 
        $ctxt.Load($fvs); 
        $ctxt.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach ($v in $versions){ 
           $v.Url
   }
}
```

The URLs are like `_vti_history/<versionLabel>/<path/to/file>`, is it possible to download these URLs or is there a more direct PnP solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below PnP PowerShell code:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url <url> 
$ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List <MyDocLibrary>
$ctx= Get-PnPContext
foreach ($item in $ListItems)
{
        $file = $item.file
        $ctx.load($file)
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        Write-Host $file.Name,$file.UIVersionLabel
}
```

Source of the above code:

[How Do I get the version of a file using PnP Powershell](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint-developer/how-do-i-get-the-version-of-a-file-using-pnp-powershell/m-p/156100)

**Other Approaches:**

**Download all version of a file using the PowerShell and SharePoint web service (Versions.asmx):**

```
# ******* Variables Section ******************
#Define these variables 
$WebURL="http://sharepoint.crescent.com/sites/Operations/"
$FilePath ="http://sharepoint.crescent.com/sites/Operations/docs/designDoc.docx"
$TargetFolder = "C:\Downloads"
# *********************************************

#Web Service URL
$WebServiceURL =$WebURL+"_vti_bin/Versions.asmx"
$WebService = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $WebServiceURL -UseDefaultCredential
$WebService.URL=$WebServiceURL

#Get File name from file path
$FileName = $FilePath.Substring($FilePath.LastIndexOf("/")+1,($FilePath.Length-$FilePath.LastIndexOf("/")-1))

#Create the Target Library if it doesn't exists
    if (!(Test-Path -path $TargetFolder))
       {   
             #If it doesn't exists, Create
             $TargetFolder = New-Item $TargetFolder -type directory
       }


#Call web service method "GetVersions" to retrieve versions collection
$FileVersions = $WebService.GetVersions($FilePath).Result
 foreach($File in $FileVersions)
 { 
  #Frame the File name : E.g. 1.0_Filename.ext
  $VersionFileName = "$($TargetFolder)\$($File.version)_$($FileName)"
  write-host $VersionFileName
  $webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
     $webclient.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
  write-host $File.url
     $webclient.DownloadFile($File.url,$VersionFileName)
  Write-Host "Downloaded version: $($File.Version)"
 }
```

Source of the above code:

[Download All Versions of a Document in SharePoint using PowerShell - Web Services](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/07/download-all-document-versions-using-web-services-powershell.html)

**Download all versions of a file using the SharePoint PowerShell server object model:**

```
 Get-PSSnapin -Registered
 if(-not (Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)){Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"}

$spSiteURL = "https://intranet.contoso.com/sites/jayant/"
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb -Identity $spSiteURL
$spDocFolder = $spWeb.GetFolder("Docs")
$spFileCollection = $spDocFolder.Files
$dlProps = @{
    DownloadURL = ''
    DownloadFileName = ''
}
$dlobjects = @()
ForEach($file in $spFileCollection){
$spFileVersionCollection= $file.Versions;
#===============get URLs of old versions===============
    if ($spFileVersionCollection) {
         ForEach($version in $spFileVersionCollection){
            $downloadversURL = $version.Url;
            $dlobject = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $dlProps
            $dlobject.DownloadURL=$downloadversURL;
            $dlobject.DownloadFileName = $version.VersionLabel + "_" +$file.Name;
           $dlobjects +=$dlobject;
         }
    }
#===============get URLs of old versions===============

#================get URLs of latest versions==========
    $downloadlatestURL = $file.Url;
    $dlobject = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $dlProps
    $dlobject.DownloadFileName = "Latest" + $file.UIVersionLabel + "_" +$file.Name;
   $dlobject.DownloadURL=$downloadlatestURL;
    $dlobjects +=$dlobject;
#================get URLs of latest versions==========
}
#================download version files================
$destination="C:\Users\jayant\Desktop\version files\"
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
ForEach($dlobj in $dlobjects){
    $fullURL = $spSiteURL + $dlobj.DownloadURL;
    $destinationFullPath=$destination + $dlobj.DownloadFileName;
    $webclient.DownloadFile($fullURL, $destinationFullPath);
}
#================download version files================
```

Source of the above code:

[Download all File Versions from SharePoint](https://www.kalmstrom.com/Tips/PowerShell/SharePoint-Download-Versions.htm)

Comment: Thank you for your long response. Unfortunately it doesn't answer fully my question. The first approach is the one I had cited in my question from the Microsoft community site. It provides the `versionLabel`s but how to download the content of all these versions? 
I cannot make the web service way for some reasons, and the last one from _Kalmstrom_ is not accessible for me as I'm just a site collection admin, not a SP admin. I cannot install `Get-SPWeb` as it's in **SharePoint Server Module** (if I am wrong, please tell me how).

Comment: My question is related to this question from 2017 [how-to-download-fileversion-content-from-sharepoint-online-using-csom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47327780/how-to-download-fileversion-content-from-sharepoint-online-using-csom). I don't understand it anyway,..

Comment: You can use the Get-SPWeb, being a site collection administrator for that before executing the script at the beginning of script, we need to add this line : Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell    and this script Get-SPWeb has to be executed in any of the SharePoint server.

Comment: I tried this command in the past, but I've always bumped into a cryptic result:
`Add-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
Add-PSSnapin : Aucun composant logiciel enfichable n'a été inscrit pour Windows PowerShell version 5.
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Add-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
+ ~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument : (Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell:String) [Add-PSSnapin], PSArgumentExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddPSSnapInRead,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddPSSnapinCommand` and `Get-PSSnapin -Registered` is empty. 
`

Comment: Sorry for the sentence `Aucun composant logiciel enfichable n'a été inscrit pour Windows PowerShell version 5` in French. I don't know how to translate accurately. Is it `No snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell version 5.`?. I've read I could use `Import-Module` instead, but with no success.

Comment: Use this this command: Get-PSSnapin -Registered    -if does not fix the issue , run the below command: cd C:\Program Files (x86)\SolarWinds\Orion SDK\SWQL Studio\
$framework=$([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment]::GetRuntimeDirectory())
Set-Alias installutil "$($framework)installutil.exe"
installutil SwisPowerShell.dll   source: https://thwack.solarwinds.com/t5/Discussions/No-snap-ins-have-been-registered-for-Windows-PS-v-5-0/m-p/80754

Comment: Nothing for Get-PSSnapin and I don't understand the link with `Orion SDK` module. (I wrote "with `Microsoft.Sharepoint`" by mistake in a previous comment that I deleted).

Answer (score 1):

For SharePoint Online I'm using following code:

```
    Get-PnPFile -Url $item.ServerRelativeUrl -Path $destinationFolderPath -AsFile -Force # Latest version
    $ctx= Get-PnPContext
    $ctx.Load($item.Versions)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    foreach ($version in $item.Versions)
    {
        $versionValue = $version.VersionLabel
        $str = $version.OpenBinaryStream()
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        $filename =  (Split-Path $item.ServerRelativeUrl -Leaf) + "." + $versionValue
        $filepath = Join-Path $destinationFolderPath $filename
        $fs = New-Object IO.FileStream $filepath ,'Append','Write','Read'
        $str.Value.CopyTo($fs) # Older version
        $fs.Close()
    }
```